# formatting a date in an array

Tags: java, arrays, date

I have a 2-dimensional array which retrieves a date from a database. I want the value to be formatted in days only, "12","13". How can I achieve this this?

This is my code:

```
String headerQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT attendance FROM Attendance;";
            Object[][] headerQueryResult = connectToDB(headerQuery);

            for(int x = 0; x < headerQueryResult.length; x++){
                for(int y=0; y < headerQueryResult[x].length; y++){
                    System.out.print(headerQueryResult[x][y]+" ");

                }
                System.out.println("---");
            }
```

Comment: How result of query looks like? Post an example?

Comment: @T.G 2014-05-14 00:00:00
2014-05-16 00:00:00
2014-05-17 00:00:00

Answer (score 3):

Try this, assuming you're getting an array of dates back.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");

<loop>
System.out.print(format.format((Date) headerQueryResult[x]);
```

Comment: it says inconvertible types

Comment: What is your `connectToDB` returning?

Comment: I mean, what kind of object?

Answer (score 0):

very simple

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");

int day = Integer.parseInt(sdf.format( dateObject ))
```